# CANOpenNode stack heap variable resets when a new function is entered

Tags: c, embedded, can-bus, freertos, canopen

I have integrated CANopenNodeStack with my STM32 FreeRTOs based code . Below is my code

And here is the repository I am using for CANopenNode stack for STM32 https://github.com/CANopenNode/CanOpenSTM32/tree/master

```
void canopennode_mtr(void* argument) {
    uint32_t ticks = osKernelGetTickCount();

    canopen_init();
    while (1) {

        canopen_app_process();
        
            }

        // Sleep for 1ms, you can decrease it if required, in the canopen_app_process we will double check to make sure 1ms passed
        ticks += 1;
        osDelayUntil(ticks);
       
        }
        }

void canopen_init(void) {
      
    //Assign CANOpenNode parameters
    CANopenNodeSTM32 canOpenNodeSTM321;
    canOpenNodeSTM321.CANHandle = &hcan1;
    canOpenNodeSTM321.HWInitFunction = MX_CAN1_Init;
    canOpenNodeSTM321.timerHandle = &htim14;
    canOpenNodeSTM321.desiredNodeID = 0x11;
    canOpenNodeSTM321.baudrate = 500;
    canopen_app_init(&canOpenNodeSTM321);
    }
```

`CANopenNodeSTM32* canopenNodeSTM32;` is a variable which gets filed during initialization and its in heap . And this variable resets to 0 when I enter `canopen_app_process` (`canopen_app_process`is a function from CANopenNode Stack).
My question is there a obvious reason in freeRTOS for a heap to reset or am I missing something ?
Note : I am not asking specific to CANopenNode Stack , I just wanna understand general reasons for the heap variable reset

Comment: I don't really see how the posted code is relevant to your problem. However, `canopen_init` seems fishy, are you sure it makes a hard copy of the passed pointed-at data?

Comment: In the future make sure to tag questions like this with [tag:embedded] to get attention to the question from the right kind of people, as well as [tag:c] for code formatting purposes.

Comment: I only see here a automatic variable `canOpenNodeSTM321`, which is not valid after `canopen_init()` function is left. There is no heap involved nor a static variable.